# Preventing a Div From Expanding - Used as an Input

Tags: html, css

I have a div that s being used as an input box.

```
<div class="div_input" contentEditable="true" onkeyup="DoThing()" id="an_id_value">455</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
.div_input {
    background-color: white;
    outline:1px solid darkgray;
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

When you type in the box with characters that are longer than the width the following happens:

On Chrome it acts just like I would like it expands but retains it visual text. On Firefox Quantum it will overrun the other elements to the right.

How can I prevent this behavior? I have tried wrapping it in a fix of fixed width but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `word-break: break-all;` so all words break when they hit the limit. Something like this:

```css
.div_input {
    background-color: white;
    outline:1px solid darkgray;
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 100px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_input" contentEditable="true" onkeyup="DoThing()" id="an_id_value">455</div>
```

Here you have it on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c61askwy/1/

Thanks to [VXp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357468/preventing-a-div-from-expanding-used-as-an-input/47357620?noredirect=1#comment81668145_47357620) for pointing out the snippet didn't have the solution hehe